# How to reset Windows trusted certificates store to its default

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

Over time I have installed several additional trusted CA certificates to Windows trust store, sometimes because an app pushed me to do so, other times for reasons of development and testing.

Is there any command to restore the default (or currently MS recommended) trusted CA certificates and delete any other entries?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been migrated to SuperUser at the time.

Comment: @schroeder why this question become offtopic after 5 years?

Comment: @qdinar because it is not about security, but about how to do something in Windows, It came to light when someone tried to answer it 5 years later.

Comment: @schroeder how it is not about security? this is like https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106345/check-root-certificates-and-certificate-authorities-on-new-pc . i come here from there. security implications of having bad certificates are described there. answers of this answer that. maybe you think that is also offtopic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the following simple method to remove the locally trusted CA certificates not present in the official and current Microsoft Certificate Trust List:

First download Sigcheck (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) and then execute:

```
>sigcheck.exe -tuv
... 
Listing valid certificates not rooted to the Microsoft Certificate Trust List:

User\Root:
   Test Purpose CA
        Cert Status:    Valid
        Valid Usage:    All
        Cert Issuer:    Some development Root CA
        Serial Number:  01
        Thumbprint:     9CB31B0AE15867B5E29C4F7E21FE195C2AF24FE3
        Algorithm:      sha1RSA
        Valid from:     2:10 PM 2/5/2015
        Valid to:       2:10 PM 2/5/2025
   LLAMA.PE Root CA - R2
        Cert Status:    Valid
        Valid Usage:    All
        Cert Issuer:    Some third party Root CA
        Serial Number:  01 E0 DA 86 CC 7D 58 ED D8 62 E6 47 A2
        Thumbprint:     1B4AEFF4FB8E2BEFEB3A8FE60D03D24269AB4A6B
        Algorithm:      sha256RSA
        Valid from:     7:00 PM 3/14/2017
        Valid to:       7:00 PM 3/14/2037
...
```

Then simply delete all the displayed CAs with something like `certmgr.msc`.

**Notes**

- This method will only help to delete locally trusted CA certificates that don't exist in the Microsoft Certificate Trust List, but it won't install the Microsoft Certificate Trust List CAs not currently installed in the local store (e.g. the manually removed ones).
- This checks the current user store, not the machine store. For checking the machine store, just omit the `u` in the arguments.
- The output seems to include only valid certificates, e.g. I've observed that a locally trusted CA with a signature that Windows was unable to validate wasn't listed and I had to check it and remove it manually.

Credits to the following site, http://woshub.com/how-to-check-trusted-root-certification-authorities-for-suspicious-certs/.

Comment: `I've observed that a locally trusted CA with a signature that Windows was unable to validate wasn't listed and I had to check it and remove it manually.` But isn't that a complete deal-breaker? Can't those certificates still pose a threat somehow?

Answer (score 12):

**Theoretically,** you could apply the following method:

1. Delete all root CA certificates except the ones that are absolutely needed by Windows itself, as indicated [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/trusted-root-certificates-are-required).
2. Install the current list of trusted root CA from the [current package](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983%28v=ws.11%29). Note that validation of this package requires that you still trust one of the "necessary" root CA, which is why you must keep them in the first step.

I emphasize that *I have not tested this method*. As a preparatory step, you may want to first make a backup of all these certificates: run `certmgr.msc`, open the `Root` store, select them all (e.g. with Ctrl-A), then right-click and choose to export them all as a PKCS#7 file. That file will contain a copy of all the certificates, which should allow you to repair things, if the method above fails in some way. There again, the recovery is untested.

Be wary of the multiplicity of stores. `certmgr.msc` shows an aggregate view containing certificates from various sources ("physical stores"). To understand what you are about to do, in the certificate manager, right-click on the **Certificates** node (root node of the tree in the left pane), select **View** then **Options**, and select the **Physical certificate stores** box. This process is described in [this blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20160215235723/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/muaddib/archive/2013/10/18/understanding-certificate-stores-and-publishing-certificates-for-smart-card-logon.aspx) (with screenshots).

Comment: So there's no automated version that doesn't risk making Windows unusable?

Comment: There should be, but there isn't. The second link ("current package") is redirected now.

Comment: Do you know what would be the correct way to request this feature to MS?.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) VM or [download a pre-made VM by microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines) (Premade VM will include a few extra certs for code signing and visual studio)
2. Install Windows 10 [here is a wrapper that uses the official Windows 10 Media Creation Tool, but it will include enterprise releases and serials pre-activating your ISO](https://gist.github.com/AveYo/c74dc774a8fb81a332b5d65613187b15)
3. Load mmc.msc
4. Add certificates snap-in
5. Choose "computer"
6. Note the certificates listed
7. Export what you are missing and copy them to your main PC
8. Back up & then delete every cert on your primary PC that you don't see in Windows 10 VM.
9. Import VM Certs into primary windows system.

Ignore the votes if they are sabotaged, this is the only solution listed here to actually reset to default. I had a lot of illegitimate and distrusted certs in my trusted certificate list thanks to the [Rootsupd.exe utility tutorial here](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/222115/edit). No bad cert detection tool, anti-virus or security software detected them. Thus I removed over 300 Trusted Root certs from my Windows 10 installation and have only 36 left without any issue. I did this because each certificate, even legit ones, increase the attack surface.

1. Create a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) VM or [download a pre-made VM by microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines) (Premade VM will include a few extra certs for code signing and visual studio)
2. Install Windows 10 [here is a wrapper that uses the official Windows 10 Media Creation Tool, but it will include enterprise releases and serials pre-activating your ISO](https://gist.github.com/AveYo/c74dc774a8fb81a332b5d65613187b15)
3. Load mmc.msc
4. Add certificates snap-in
5. Choose "computer"
6. Note the certificates listed
7. Export what you are missing and copy them to your main PC
8. Back up & then delete every cert on your primary PC that you don't see in Windows 10 VM.
9. Import VM Certs into primary windows system.

This worked better for me than any other method listed above, as I had a lot of illegitimate and distrusted certs in my trusted certificate list thanks to the [Rootsupd.exe utility tutorial here](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/222115/edit). No bad cert detection tool, anti-virus or security software detected them. Thus I removed over 300 Trusted Root certs from my Windows 10 installation and have only 36 left without any issue. I did this because each certificate, even legit ones, increase the attack surface.

Importing the entire list is not a reset to default, and is a potential security hazard, however if you want to import the entire list of 400 certs you may download the list from Windows Update:

In Powershell/CMD Run `cd C:\ps\rootsupd\` then `certutil.exe -generateSSTFromWU roots.sst`

Then In Powershell:

```
$sstStore = ( Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ps\rootsupd\roots.sst )
$sstStore | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

Or

Import certs from Windows Update using just powershell:

```
cd c:\certs\
certutil.exe -generateSSTFromWU roots.sst
$sst = ( Get-ChildItem -Path C:\certs\roots.sst )
$sst = ( Get-ChildItem roots.sst )
$sst| Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier, faster, and more up-to-date to look up the current list and use that? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/participants-list

Comment: I did not want 300-400 certs on my system that I imported using certutil. Each one adds, potentially, a security hazard. I wanted the default that came with windows.

Comment: Plus importing from windows update or that entire list is not resetting the list to default, as the user has requested.

Comment: But you could identify certs not on that list and remove them.

Comment: Its easier and faster not looking through 400 certs one at a time

Comment: I dunno, I guess I'd use the search function in Excel. But that's me...

Comment: "sigcheck.exe -tuv" does that automatically

Comment: Right .... which is the accepted answer. I'm talking about *your* answer and the lengthy steps you outlined.

Comment: Yeah, my answer is currently the only real solution listed here to actually reset certs to default.

Comment: And now you're just getting petty. Stop it,