# Check root certificates and certificate authorities on new PC

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, man-in-the-middle

First Lenovo was caught shipping Superfish with new PCs, which included a universal self-signed certificate authority, and now [Dell has been caught shipping PCs with a similar root certificate](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/11/dell-does-superfish-ships-pcs-with-self-signed-root-certificates/).

What steps can I take when I get a new PC to make sure that there are no bad certificate authorities or root certificates?

- Are there any programs that can automatically check this?
- Are there any guides that can be followed to make sure there are only standard certificate authorities and certificates installed?

Comment: Evil CAs aren't the only risk, you can very well have a rootkit that intercepts TLS without actually being visible from the system itself. THe only way to be sure (at least for software-based attacks) is to reinstall the system from a known good image like an official Microsoft ISO.

Comment: That's often not an option if you buy a new PC - you would get an OEM recovery image/disk.  To get an official Microsoft ISO, you would have to buy a new copy of Windows.

Comment: Related question: [*How can I protect myself against software installing insecure root certificates?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106343/how-can-i-protect-myself-against-software-installing-insecure-root-certificates)

Comment: Related question: 2014-10-22: [*Reset Windows trusted certificates store to its default*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71313/reset-windows-trusted-certificates-store-to-its-default)

Comment: @AndréBorie, you also need to make sure that you do not run some software from the manufacturer later. For example Dell installs a trusted root cert when Dell System Detect is run (see e.g. here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYLYG76o55c)

Comment: @x457812 that's why I recommend getting the drivers from the internal device's manufacturers directly (Nvidia, etc) rather than from the OEM.

Comment: @AndréBorie, understood. However some folks may want to run software such as Dell System Detect if they have a Dell PC because it's used for troubleshooting system defects.

Comment: @x457812 I would be really cautious about software claiming to be able to troubleshoot system issues, as they're snakeoil. Even if I trusted Dell I wouldn't run such software just because it's a waste of time, and manual debugging works much better.

Comment: @AndréBorie, some of the steps that software does is that it checks things like RAM, display, sound card, and other hardware for defects. Some of this testing cannot be done manually.

Comment: Related question: Here "RCC.exe" ("Rogue certificate checker") is used: [*How did Symantec get a certificate on my laptop?*](https://superuser.com/questions/1005226/how-did-symantec-get-a-certificate-on-my-laptop)

Comment: Considering this question is not [just for Windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/71313/147346) would be great an answer [for Debian/Ubuntu Linux](https://askubuntu.com/q/1129300/349837) ([here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003) for it is Red Hat). Or I should start another question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Edit 2015-11-25

#### "PowerShell-PKI" project looks promising

Bryan Lockwood has put a a nice project on GitHub:

- https://github.com/bklockwood/Powershell-PKI

And here's his blog post that introduced it

- Bryan Lockwood, 2015-02-24, [*Auditing Your Root Certificates*](http://www.itcookbook.net/blog/auditingyourrootcertificates) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/YL6fs).)

You can run the script like so:

1. Copy `Nov2015-WindowsRootCAList.txt` to `Nov2015-WindowsRootCAList.NOSPACES.txt`
2. Work around a bug: Manually remove the trailing space characters in `Nov2015-WindowsRootCAList.NOSPACES.txt`.
   (Otherwise the script will report EVERYTHING as untrusted.)
   (I suggest you use your favorite text editor's search-and-replace-feature and just nuke all spaces.)
3. Dot-source the script:
   `PS C:\Powershell-PKI-master> . .\Audit-TrustedRootCA.ps1 3>&1 | out-null`
4. Run the function:
   `PS C:\Powershell-PKI-master> Audit-Roots -FilePath .\Nov2015-WindowsRootCAList.NOSPACES.txt -OutputPath .\`

The script the Windows trust store (stores?) against a list of known-good hashes.

#### Hashes-list is same as from certutil.

The origin of this hash-list is not entirely clear to me.

So I decided to generate the hashes myself with a bit of Cygwin-Bash-Scripting:

```
$ certutil.exe -generateSSTFromWU wuroots.sst
$ certutil.exe -dumpPFX wuroots.sst  | grep 'Hash' | tr -d ' ' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | cut -d ':' -f2 | sed 's/$/ /' | sort > wuroots-hashes-pspkiformat.txt
```

And it turns out: the hashes from `certutil` and hashes from GitHub are in fact identical:

```
$ diff --report-identical-files -- wuroots-hashes-pspkiformat.txt Nov2015-WindowsRootCAList.txt
Files wuroots-hashes-pspkiformat.txt and Nov2015-WindowsRootCAList.txt are identical
```

#### Related Twitter Thread

This [Twitter thread started by German security researcher Hanno Böck](https://twitter.com/hanno/status/669184780790046721) led me to the PowerShell project.

---

## Maybe CertUtil and MMC to reset?

There was a great blog article last month:

- Mike MacCana, CertSimple CA, 2015-10-12, [*Yes, you can control the SSL CAs your browser trusts*](https://certsimple.com/blog/control-the-ssl-cas-your-browser-trusts) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/MWfZe).)

Mike outlines a procedure to generate an `.sst` certificate container with just the default certificates retrieved from Windows Update and then uses MMC to pick and choose from them.

```
certutil -generateSSTFromWU rootcas.sst
invoke-item rootcas.sst
```

I haven't tried this, but I'm guessing that throwing out every CA and then simple importing all the default CAs from the SST file should do **part** of the trick.

Note: I don't know how Windows handles self-signed-CAs in the "Intermediate" store or elsewhere. I *think* that store is a cache anyway and can be nuked because it will be automatically rebuilt anyway -- but I'm not certain.

## Prior art

EDIT. I just noticed that Tom Leek gave essentially the same answer to a similar question last year:

- 2014-10-22: [*Reset Windows trusted certificates store to its default*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71313/reset-windows-trusted-certificates-store-to-its-default)